# Printing jpanel data where page width is greater than height

Tags: java, swing, printing, desktop-application, jpanel

In my desktop application i need to print jPanel data on dot matrix printer where paper size should be 10x6. In java we have a restriction that width should not greater than height. But how can i accomplish my task by crossing this limit. If i set the page format with height is smaller than width it is treating it as A4 paper and feed the bottom of the paper.

If I didn't specify the page format it is printing fine but giving lot of margin(top,bottom,left,right). I am unable to change the margins. If set only the margins it is treating page as A4 and giving feed at bottom.

I need to print the data on pre printed page with alignment. Is there any other way to do this. Can I use Landscape, If so how to control the text flow (from bottom to top - X axis).

This is my code

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pageFormat = job.defaultPage();
pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
job.setPrintable(this,pageFormat);
try {
          job.print();
     } catch (PrinterException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
     }
```

paint method

```
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { 
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        g.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sans Serif", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 10));
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
        if (pf.getOrientation() == PageFormat.LANDSCAPE) {
            g2d.rotate( -Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
            g2d.translate( -pf.getImageableWidth(), 0);
        }
        else {
            g2d.rotate(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
            g2d.translate(0, -pf.getImageableHeight());
        }
        jPanel1.printAll(g2d);
        g2d.setTransform(old);
        //g2d.translate(70, 30);
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set PageFormat's orientation to landscape and rotate the content. In the print() method rotate and translate the content.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
if (contentOrientation == ORIENTATION_DOWN_UP) {
    g2d.rotate( -Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    g2d.translate( -w, 0);
}
else {
    g2d.rotate(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    g2d.translate(0, -h);
}
//paint all your content here
g2d.setTransform(old);
```

Comment: After modification it is printing at almost bottom of the page & paper feeding to the middle of the next page & also it is printing only half of the content of panel.